# Burlar a conversão automática para utf-16 no C#

Tags: c#

Preciso enviar dados para um handshake de webosocket, porém, ele parece não reconhecer as sequencias de escape em utf-16 geradas pelo c#.

a string correta é contém "\x02\x00" mas ao compilar vira "\u0002\0"

como eu poderia converter essa situação?

Comment: Olá Sloan. É importante você [edit] sua pergunta [evitando imagens para demonstrar códigos por uma série de ótimos motivos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635) e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, **acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema** (essa é a parte mais importante). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.